# Запуск web приложения на golang на VDS сервере

Tags: golang, apache, vds

Я написал простой блог на golang, в котором запускается сервер на порту 8080
Также я развернул сервер Ubuntu на VDS Timeweb (получил ip адрес, например 173.88.311.33 )
Также я установил Apache на Ubuntu который слушает порт 80, соответственно открывается стандартная страница Apache по адресу 173.88.311.33
После запуска сервера на golang по пути 173.88.311.33:8080 я получаю свой блог, все работает.
Как мне запустить его теперь по стандартному порту 80 (то есть не указывая конкретный порт — чтобы сразу по адресу 173.88.311.33 я получил свой блог), там где сейчас стоит Apache (удалять его нельзя, так как он нужен для phpMyAdmin)

Ожидаю увидеть блог по стандартному обращении к ip сервера

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1162375/4827341 . ну и дубликатов тут, конечно, полным-полно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=ProxyPassReverse

Answer (score 2):

Я разобрался.

Расскажу, вдруг кому то будет полезно.

1. Необходимо включить модули Apache **mod_proxy** и **mod_proxy_http**
   Выполняем команды в консоли:

```html
sudo a2enmod proxy 
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```

2. Редактируем дефолтный конфигурационный файл Apache, расположенный по адресу:
   ***/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf***
   Необходимо добавить следующий код:

```html
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://173.88.311.33:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://173.88.311.33:8080/
```

3. Перезапускаем Apache

```html
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Готово!